# metronome precision algorithm maths

Tags: c++, math

**IN SHORT:**
I have a method being called at 44,100 times per second. I would like to know what to do in a situation where I need a sound to be ticked at the 13781.25th method call - thats a 192 Beats Per Minute). I have the option to round off that number and make the sound tick at the 13781st method call which would mean i am making the sound tick at 0.25th too early. this equates to being 0.00000566893424 of a second too early.

after a 100 ticks im sure the delay will certainly add up. Are there any smart work arounds that sort of keeps track of the delay and when the delay gets over a certain point then maybe ± some figures to keep the beat on track again?

Here is my code below so far..

```
int counter; // used to track down the amount of times the method has been called

signalMethod(){
    if(counter % ceil(2,646,000/10) == 0){ //the ceil function turns the decimal point into a whole number so it can be used for analysis. but this will cut off delay.. and over time im sure it will add up.. which will cause the beats to fluctuate...
        playSound();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: A standard way of doing this in audio applications is to set up a double t, initially zero. Each sample, increment t by 1.0/44100.0, and check whether t>(60.0/192.0). If so, call your metronome function and decrement t by 60.0/192.0. The amount left in t once it has been decremented acts exactly in the way that your second paragraph describes, to prevent the error building up over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is just another variation of the problem addressed "Bresenham's Algorithm", but instead of incrementing the Y coordinate of a line drawn with a certain slope (the slope would be the beat frequency), you're emitting ticks.

[Wikipedia on Bresenham's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: Ah yes I'm familiar with this algorithm in regards to plotting pixels onto a screen to represent a line for example. I understand that in both situations we have to deal with an error accumulation value. However im not sure how to then go about adjusting the accuracy of the tick over time if the accumulation error is great enough to call for making a change in the tick pattern in terms of what new sample to then make it tick at to then be precise again.

Comment: @Pavan: the suggested method avoids error accumulation (if done with integers as in Bresenhams's algorithm). It will introduce a little jitter, your beats won't all be at perfect times, but as long as they are within about 1 (maybe even up to 10) millisecond of where they should be, no one will notice, not by ear. Again, there's no error accumulation here.